# How any routing protocol packet reaches(flows of operations) from NIC card (physical layer) to any Routing (OSPF/RIP/BGP) daemon?

Tags: networking, routing, kernel, bgp, ospf

The problem is rearding the routing protocol packet flow in any linux/unix device where multiple routing protocol daemons are running.

How any routing protocol packet reaches(flows of operations) from NIC card (physical layer) to any Routing (OSPF/RIP/BGP) daemon ?

Answer (score 11):

You didn't specified what kernel are you talking about.
From BSD's point of view it's all explained in [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 2: The Implementation By Gary R. Wright, W. Richard Stevens](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780201633542)

Short version follows:

1. Frame arrives at NIC's rx descriptor ring. Through DMA it gets transferred to RX ring
   in RAM.
2. Driver converts device specific descriptors in RX ring to some kind of general network kernel structure (e.g. `mbuf` / `mbuf_cluster` or `sk_buff`). Also here packet gets copied to [bpf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bpf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208-current&format=html) device.
3. In `ether_input` depending on protocol and address families of the frame it gets processed by corresponding `protosw` (protocol switch) array entry.
4. Then after `ip_input` or `tcp_input` / `udp_input` datagram arrives at socket layer to the corresponding routing daemon's `so_rcvbuf` (socket receive buffer).
5. From this point routing daemon usually gets notified about pending data on socket via some kind of I/O notification facility ([select(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) / [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) / [epoll(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll) / [kqueue(2)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&format=html)) and uses [recv(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) on that socket to extract packets' payload. Here `(e)glibc` / `libc` / `libSystem` takes it's place.
6. Routing daemon does it's magic and alters kernels' routing table(s) via routing sockets ([PF_ROUTE](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/rtsock.c) in BSD derivatives or [PF_NETLINK](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=PF_NETLINK)'s [NETLINK_ROUTE](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=rtnetlink) in Linux)

Answer (score 8):

Routing daemons and suites manipulate the routing table in the Kernel. So packets down't flow through the routing daemon, but rather packets get routed according to the routing table.

When it comes to which routes get priority when there are two choices of equal specificity (the most specific route always wins) in the routing table, it is which ever one has the best (lowest) `metric` (see `route`). In Cisco land is called '[Administrative Distance](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094195.shtml).' Different protocols such as RIP and BGP have default metrics. I am not sure if there is a Linux specific reference, but if you look at the administrative distance link I would venture a guess that routing daemons use the same priority.

As far as the routing protocol packets themselves, it depends on the  routing protocol, but they generally use standard transport protocols. For example, BGP uses a TCP/IP session on port 179. So the daemon would just bind a socket accordingly.

Comment: Dear Kyle Brandt, thank you very much. Would you please confirm my final understanding: "When any packet arrives at router interface, first interface's Layer-2 forwarding table lookup will be done(like Cisco express forwarding), then if needed, the routing table lookup will be performed on that interface's routing table(patricia trie or hash table lookup depending upon implementation). At this point it is assumed that, all the routing daemons are running at Fully loaded state and populated latest routing info at interface's routing table".

Comment: In BSD for example there is no separate so-called "switching table" - `arp` entries are located as nodes in the same radix(patricia) trie as IPv4 routes.

Comment: Dear SaveTheRbtz, thanks so much, now the idea is really clear.